# window.onresize event function execution[open]

Tags: javascript

i want to change the size of a div respective to the change in viewport dimensions. but the following doesn't work. why?

```
function changeDivDimensions() {

code...

}

window.onresize = changeDivDimensions();
```

Comment: `function changeDivDimensions() {..`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i didn't get you?

Comment: i'm sorry i mistyped it in the question. my original code was correct

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following code.

```
window.onresize=changeDivDimensions;
```

Notice that there are no brackets after the function name.

Edit: Explaination.

If you call the function using this form "changeDivDimensions()", it will execute on page load. However, by calling the function using the form "changeDivDimensions", it assigns the function to the onresize event, which executes it when the window resizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (edited after Juhana's comment) :

```
function changeDivDimensions() {
    //code...
}

window.onresize = changeDivDimensions;
```

[**New Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4DET7/1/)

Comment: can i not used a named function?

Comment: @user3641556 You can, but you shouldn't call it. Change it to `window.onresize = changeDivDimensions;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onresize = function(){
    changeDivDimensions();
};
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4DET7/1/)

> `window.onresize` is used to add the event listener and a event
>   listener is always added as a method